# What is the .Net core equivalent of KerberosRequestorSecurityToken?

Tags: c#, .net-core, kerberos, asp.net-core-2.2

I am specifically trying to replicate a few lines of code, but cannot seem to find the equivalent in .net core.  Any help in replacing would be appreciated, or at least some direction in where to look.  I did try looking into Kerberos.NET but it didn't seem to have this kind of functionality.

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.KerberosRequestorSecurityToken Ticket = null;
try
{
     Ticket = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.KerberosRequestorSecurityToken(UserSPN);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, I came across a blog post published the day I posted this question and I've been messing around with it.  It does effectively replace the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.KerberosRequestorSecurityToken class.  The blog is from Harmj0y, who effectively wrote PowerView and helped write Sharphound.  My next step is trying to replace the interop features, since the .dll files referenced won't be available on *nix type systems.  That may end up being another question.  The blogs link is below.

https://posts.specterops.io/kerberoasting-revisited-d434351bd4d1

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead.